# What is the proper way of developing a real world application in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications

Well, I am afraid, this might turn into a general opinion question and might be turned down by moderators. I can only request, let me get few answers before flagging the question. This I think is the best platform for such a question.

I entered the `ReactJS` world a few weeks ago. I have seen few really impressing videos and tutorials on it. Now that I am little familiar with the React, I decided to make an app and I was able to make a little Todo App with it and Flux.

While developing this app, I underwent various doubt which I raise below as my questions.

1. Is it good, safe and doable to use libraries like `jQuery and _.js` with React. If not, is there any library that React recommends for various JS utilities.
2. How is the DOM manipulated in React, say I have to `show/hide, add/remove` class from various node. How do I go about it?
3. Currently, I am aware of Flux (`EventEmitter, Dispatcher`) to maintain data modularity in my app, using JS import an export. Is this the only way of doing it. Can't react be very well used with ES5?

I am currently from Angular JS world. How different it is going to be to make real world complex applications in React?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use any libraries with react. Even you can use angular with react. I will say **Angular + React = Speed**

You can hide/show classes based on state variable in react. React will update only that component whose state has been modified and that is the reason why react is fast.

Answer (score 0):

1. jQuery must not be used with ReactJS as jQuery interacts with physical DOM and makes performance slower while working with huge html (For example, binding 1000 rows in a table). Whereas ReacJS has totally opposite concept. It keeps virtual copy of DOM and only patches the actual changes to physical DOM which increases drastic performance boost.
2. You can use state variables to manage show/hide element or add/remove class based on any condition. As and when you change the value of state, ReactJS will re-render respective component and updates the change to browser if any.
3. Flux and Redux are the architecture to manage the State out of your React components and provides undirectional data flow to communicate with other React components.
4. As far as ES5 is concerned, there is no restriction on using it with ReactJS. However, ES6 gives you more object oriented paradigm which ES5 is lacking. It is up to you whether to use ES5 or ES6

There is no complexity with ReactJS while developing real word application. Initially, ReactJS seems to bit complex to learn as it has very different concepts. But, as and when you are getting familiar with ReactJS, you will realize how React is fast, scalable and easier implementation.